# Why do I get different font sizes?

Tags: android, css, mobile

I have tried to make a small page mobile friendly with Skeleton ([Link](http://www.getskeleton.com)), but it fails completely, at least in on Android. I include the first tow css files from Skeleton in my page. There is no other css in the page at the moment.

Looking at the page in my desktop browsers I see no problem. However in my mobile the font size in the first class="sixteen columns" div p is much smaller than in the following div p.

I can see no other differences between them so I have no clue to what is happening. Please look at the page here:

[Click here](http://ourcomments.org/psych/viewport-fonts.html)

I see the same font-size difference in Chrome, Firefox and Opera on Android.

If I just include base.css - which is the file in Skeleton handling font-size - I see no problems. However when I include the second file, skeleton.css - which does not mention fonts - the problem with the different font sizes appear.

Here is a link to skeleton.css:

[css link](https://github.com/dhg/Skeleton/blob/master/stylesheets/skeleton.css)

I would be glad if someone could explain what is happening. I have no clue right now.

(Skeleton has been mentioned some times here on Stackoverflow, precisely for what I want to do, i.e. make pages that works both at the desktop and in a mobile. And Skeleton is very simple so I thought it was fit for my purpuse. BTW skeleton seems abondoned, but that is not relevant here.)

Comment: Thanks for changing the link to something more common here, @Aravinth!

Comment: Why don't you used a standard style for your Font?

Comment: You need to include code sufficient for reproducing the problem, in the question itself. Links are not enough, especially when they point to live pages.

Comment: Good point, @JukkaK.Korpela. Normally I would agree to that, but in this case I you need a page to test on your mobile. And Skeleton has not been changed for 2 years now. So I thought it would be better to add code later, when someone has been able to tell something.

Comment: But, ..., your comment may have solved the problem, @JukkaK.Korpela! I tried to make a smaller example. Then I noticed that I had not added this line, <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />, from 
https://github.com/dhg/Skeleton/blob/master/index.html. I normally skip <meta>-tags, but this one did something. I have to look up what it did! ;-) -- Now if someone would explain what that meta-tag does that would be a very good answer here!

Comment: Hm, looking around I see the meta-tag is really what I wanted. The problem was perhaps that I assumed that mobile browsers did this in some reasonable way. Why should I have to tell them this? ;-)